# How can I be notified of important updates/news to the Monero software?

Tags: hard-fork, update, fork-notification

Monero forks twice a year at roughly predictable times. However, it is easy to forget about it, and you end up forked off if you don't update your software in time. How can I be notified of these forks and other important announcements such as any emergency fork that might happen ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now a monero-announce mailing list on which such important announcements will be made:

https://lists.getmonero.org/postorius/lists/monero-announce.lists.getmonero.org/